# How to plot a matrix with 3D style

Tags: plotting, matrix, graphics3d

I have a list like

```
SeedRandom[1]
MatrixForm[list = RandomInteger[5, {5, 5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can plot it with `MatrixPlot` directly with 2D style

```
MatrixPlot[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I hope to plot it with 3D style.This is current method

```
Histogram3D[Catenate[Table @@@ Catenate[MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, list, {2}]]], 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I don't know how to plot a matrix with real number.Such as

```
SeedRandom[1]
MatrixForm[list = RandomReal[5, {5, 5}]]
```

Is there any elegant method can do this?

Comment: Something like a [cityplot](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/cityplots.html), then. How do you want negative or complex entries to be handled?

Comment: @J.M. Good link,and “For complex matrices the modulus (absolute value) of each element is displayed” as the description.

Comment: [This discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117913/34008) might be of interest (or useful.)

Comment: @yode Why do you want to plot the matrix in 3D? Is it because the cell colors of `MatrixPlot` are not informative enough?

Comment: @AntonAntonov Actually form a request of newer,and I don't know how to do.So post here for help..

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Height-dependent filling color in 3D Data Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3333/89)?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks for your link.It's seem it is a duplicated question indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ListPlot3D` with `InterpolationOrder -> 0`:

```
ListPlot3D[list, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 Mesh -> None, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But unfortunately I've failed to find a way to color the block under each square accordingly with `FillingStyle` or with other means domestic to `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Fun,if you can make the color of those transparent pillar same to its top-face,I will accept this answer for its concise.

Comment: @yode Yeah, now that is the hard part I hoped you won't ask for : )

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but I should admit that coloring boxes according to top color seems impossible for `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Yep,I have tried that just. But I like this solution still. :)

Comment: The original matrix was 5x5 and the plot is 4x4

Answer (score 13):

Graphics primitives is quite elegant:

```
box[h_, {x_, y_}] := Cuboid[{x, y, 0}, {x + 1, y + 1, h}]
Graphics3D@MapIndexed[box, list, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is no less elegant with custom styling:

```
box[h_, {x_, y_}] := {
  ColorData["Rainbow", h/Max[list]],
  Cuboid[{x, y, 0}, {x + 1, y + 1, h}]
  }
Graphics3D@MapIndexed[box, list, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's an example with the color function that is used by `MatrixPlot`, see J.M.'s comment below:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If `MatrixPlot[]`'s coloring is desired, [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5959839#5959839) is the necessary color function.

Comment: @J.M. Nice, especially because of the way it was found out. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

Also:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomReal[5, {5, 5}];
```

**BarChart3D:**

```
BarChart3D[Reverse /@ list, ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
   BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   "Canvas" -> False, "FaceGrids" -> None][[1]] // 
 Graphics3D[#, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/GoldenRatio}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**DiscretePlot3D:**

```
iF = Interpolation[Join @@ MapIndexed[Composition[Reverse, List], list, {2}]];

DiscretePlot3D[iF[i, j], {i, 1, Dimensions[list][[1]]}, {j, 1, Dimensions[list][[2]]}, 
 ExtentSize -> Full, FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**ListPlot3D:**

```
Normal[ListPlot3D[list, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None]] /. 
 {Line[__] :> Sequence[], Polygon[x : {__},  VertexColors -> {col_, ___}, ___] :>  
 {col, EdgeForm[], Opacity[.9], Cuboid @@ ({{1, 1, 0}, 1} Sort[x][[{1, -1}]])}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: see also: [How can I imitate the style of a certain 3D bar chart?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21460/125)

Comment: It's very feauty here,thanks very much.And thanks for your link.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a plot based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117982/34008) of ["Plotting “Terrain” with “Water” on them Using BarChart3D"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117913/34008)

```
{n, m} = Dimensions[list];
{cx, cy} = {1/4, 1/4};
Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.1], 
  Cuboid[{1/2, 1/2, 0}, {n + 1/2, m + 1/2, 0}], 
  Table[Tooltip[{Red, Opacity[0.1], 
     Cuboid[{i, j, 0}, {i + cx, j + cy, list[[i, j]]}], Blue, 
     Opacity[0.3], 
     Cuboid[{i, j, list[[i, j]]}, {i + cx, j + cy, list[[i, j]]}]}, 
    BarChart[list[[i]], PlotLabel -> Row[{"row:", i}], 
     ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]], {i, n}, {j, m}]}, Axes -> True, 
 Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {n/Max[n, m], m/Max[n, m], 1/3}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The idea is to make the plot more informative by (1) making the bars to be thinner and more transparent, and (2) providing a tooltip showing a 2D BarChart with stacked layout for each row.